# D'autres expressions idiomatiques pour dire « Ce n'est pas la fleur des pois » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, synonymes, superlatifs

En anglais (parmi d'autres) il y a plusieurs expressions péjoratives mais pas très malpolies qui veulent dire [ce n'est pas la fleur des pois](https://www.littre.org/definition/pois) pour décrire quelq'un qui fait des bêtises ou qui n'est pas tops, pas un premier de classe. *Not the brightest crayon in the box* (ce crayon cire n'est pas très lumineux) ou *Not the sharpest tool in the shed* (cet outil n'est pas le plus pointu/efficace du hangar) sont des expressions plutôt figées ; on ne dit pas l'inverse à l'affirmatif pour faire un compliment.  **Quelqu'un qui n'a pas inventé la poudre,** c'est peut-être un bon exemple.  À l'affirmatif ça ne serait pas très sincère (au moins problématique sur le plan interpersonnel) d'entendre dire « Tu penses qu t'as inventé la poudre ou quoi? »

Il est toujours très possible de faire la négation pour arriver au sens péjoratif, je cherche plutôt des expressions figées au négatif, *c'est vite mais ce n'est pas le Concorde* par exemple.  Par contre *Il est gentil mais il n'est pas [cf.] **le roi des rois***.  Cette dernière expression se dit aussi toute seule ; elle s'utilise afin de dire du bien.  Je cherche plutôt des expressions fondamentalement ou exclusivement négatives au niveau de syntaxe.

Je note *ne pas avoir inventé le fil qui a coupé le beurre* et je cherche d'autres expressions idiomatiques similaires.  C'est X mais pas le plus X ou plutôt Y.

Comment: [à couper le beurre,qui a coupé le beurre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+couper+le+beurre%2Cqui+a+coup%C3%A9+le+beurre&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), [fil qui a coupé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fil+qui+a+coup%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), [à couper le beurre](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A0%20couper%20le%20beurre%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Comment: Parmi d'autres _langues_ ? (Je crois que c'est plutôt évident qu'il y a d'autres langues qui comprennent de telles expressions péjoratives.)

Comment: "bête à manger du foin", il n'a pas inventé l'eau chaude.

Comment: J'aurais dit "Il n'a pas inventé l'eau tiède". Car chauffer l'eau c'est une invention. Mais la chauffer à moitié - ou la mélanger à de l'eau froide - c'est très idiot. Donc s'il ne sait même pas faire ça, c'est vraiment grave.

Comment: @Necklondon: Je suis d'accord sur le plan sémantique, mais [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invent%C3%A9+l%27eau+chaude%2Cinvent%C3%A9+l%27eau+ti%C3%A8de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) indique que "inventé l'eau chaude" est plus de 2 fois plus fréquent qu' "inventé l'eau tiède".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Il n'a pas inventé l'eau chaude.
- Elle ne casse pas trois pattes à un canard.
  Pas idiomatique, mais intérressant néanmoins:
- Il n’est pas très fute-fute.

Comment: Surtout avec fute-fute c'est il ou elle n'est pas fute-fute, ça répond bien à la question de syntagme figé.

Answer (score 1):

Following the syntax of **not the most/best X of the X or Y**...:

- ne pas être le couteau le plus fin du tiroir
- Sur un sapin de Noël, c’est pas vraiment la boule la plus brillante
- ne pas avoir la lumière à tous les étages
- ne pas avoir toutes ses frites dans le même sachet (Belgique)

Several phrases given in the negative as an invective are  many things that a person described with these traits would not have invented, which seems a more common trope in French than just sliced bread or the wheel. Language is productive.  These expressions do not follow the same structure I was looking for above but have the same semantic sense, so I include them for that, some from [Wiktionaire](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_pas_avoir_invent%C3%A9_la_poudre#fr).

All of these start with **ne pas avoir inventé**:

**Ne pas avoir inventé . . . :**

- l'eau pétillante
- l'eau tiède
- l'eau sucrée
- la boule à caravane
- la chute des feuilles
- le cords à tourner le vent
- la machine à courber les bananes
- le bouton à quatre trous (QC)
- le bidon à deux litres

C'est très productif comme expression mais c'est pas la fin du chapitre.  Je continue la liste des expressions dans la catégorie **de ne pas avoir inventé** pour le sens, pas pour la syntaxe de la question.

Answer (score 0):

Plusieurs expressions viennent à l'esprit, mais à utiliser avec parcimonie, car elles sont assez négatives, si ce n'est insultantes :

*C'est pas une flèche*.

*C'est pas une lumière*.

*Il ne percute pas*.

*C'est pas un as*.

Le [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_pas_avoir_invent%C3%A9_la_poudre#fr) offre de nombreux autres exemples.

Comment: Mais ça se dit « c'est un as, c'est une lumière » à l'affirmatif, n'est-ce pas, pas que dans le sens de « Il a une belle tête de vainqueur » ?  C'est un bon lien pour les phrases figées au négatif de toute façon, merci.

Comment: @livresque Oui, ça peut se dire.